# how to get the file path from button click and print it on textbox VB6

Tags: vb6

I have a button and a textbox and I want to make the button to open the folder by a default path.

I will give example:

```
    'C:\Folder\...

    Dim path as string
    path = "C:\Folder\.."
    Dim fso
    set fso = createobject("Scripting FileSystemObjh)
```

I tried some method where it only opens the folder but doesn't get the file path so not what I want to do.

And when I select the file and click okay the file path to be printed on the textbox.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you need, the following should point you in the right direction.  First, select the following Component:

> Microsoft Common Dialog Control 6.0 (SP6)

Second, select the following Reference:

> Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Third, drop a CommonDialog control onto your form along with the CommandButton and TextBox.  Type the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim fso As FileSystemObject
   Dim path As String
   
   path = "c:\temp\"
   
   CommonDialog1.InitDir = path
   CommonDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
   CommonDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt"
   CommonDialog1.DialogTitle = "Select File"
   CommonDialog1.ShowOpen
   
   Text1.Text = CommonDialog1.FileName
   
   Set fso = New FileSystemObject
   'use fso to do whatever you need
End Sub
```